# Use of DataStructure for this scenario

Tags: java, data-structures

I am having data in the following form -

```
01/04/2011  - {00:00,1.0} ; {01:00,2.0} ; {02:00,1.5} ;{04:00,2.3} 
02/04/2011  - {00:00,2.0} ; {01:00,2.1} ; {02:00,1.5} ;{04:00,2.3}
03/04/2011  - {00:00,3.0} ; {01:00,2.0} ; {02:00,1.6} ;{04:00,2.3}
04/04/2011  - {00:00,1.0} ; {01:00,2.5} ; {02:00,1.57} ;{04:00,2.3}
05/04/2011  - {00:00,1.9} ; {01:00,2.7} ; {02:00,1.5} ;{04:00,2.3}
06/04/2011  - {00:00,1.08} ; {01:00,2.02} ; {02:00,1.9} ;{04:00,2.3}
07/04/2011  - {00:00,1.7} ; {01:00,2.0} ; {02:00,1.10} ;{04:00,2.3}
```

I have to store them in some DataStructure so that i can access them using the dates as the key.Also for the particular day the {k,v} pairs should be ordered in the way they get inserted.

Pls suggest which is the best DataStructure to use in this scenario with the reason why it should be used. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tony its not homework...I have scenario where i need to implement this and i have no idea how to go above with this....Tried with LinkedHasMap<String ,LinkedHashMap<String,Float>> but not sure if thats a good approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) to me.

```
MultiMap<Date, SomeRecord> records = ArrayListMultiMap.create();
records.put(..., ...);
```

Comment: Yep. ArrayListMultimap to be specific.

Comment: How would you preserve the ordering of SomeRecord?

Comment: @Jeff: That's provided by [ArrayListMultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html): *When iterating through the collections supplied by this class, the ordering of values for a given key agrees with the order in which the values were added.*

Answer (score 5):

Sounds exactly like a `Map<Date,List<Record>>` to me.  If you use a `HashMap` then looking up a given date will be an O(1) operation.  There's no particular ordering using this approach.

Alternatively you could use a `LinkedHashMap` then ordering can be preserved which might be useful if you need to go through the records in date order.

Comment: If the ordering is on the values, using `IndexedRecord` as the `Record` implementation would handle the ordering.

Comment: I just re-read this - I don't believe you need to do a `List<Record>` as `IndexedRecord` implements `List`.

Comment: @Riggy: I'm pretty sure @Jeff meant `Record` to simply be an arbitrary name for the "value" data type.  He didn't mean `javax.resource.cci.Record`.  I'm sure the OP doesn't want to bring in an entirely unrelated library.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did just mean some arbitrary class.  I've never seen Record or IndexRecord class before.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data it appears that the values for each date is just a collection of numbers for each hour. So you could simply use `Map<Date, Float>` if there's always just one date and time per number. E.g. "01/04/2011 00:00" is "1.0" and "01/04/2011 01:00" is "2.0". You could keep them in order with a `TreeMap<Date, Float>` and pull just the ranges of dates you need with the `subMap()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is this structure: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

The entries are saved in order they was inserted. 
There is another good point - due the key is hashed the search in the list is done faster.